# SharePoint group not visible

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, client-object-model, groups

I created a new SharePoint group using UI. 
I do not see the group using:

```
$web.Groups | select Name
```

Why? (I need to access to the group by CSOM but the group is not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Groups` property for [Web client object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web(v=office.15).aspx)

Use [Web.SiteGroups property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.sitegroups(v=office.15).aspx) to get the collection of groups for the site collection, for example:

```
$web.SiteGroups | select Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
currentContext.load(currentUser);

var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
currentContext.load(allGroups);

var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
currentContext.load(group);
```